# splitting txt's using a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to split a series of txt files into 2 each. Below is one of the files. The first new file should contain everything before "AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES". The second file everything after this and including this string.

The next trick I would like to learn is how to fix length delimit the resulting files into csv's.

Thanks in advance.

File Example:

```
                              ENERGY RESOURCES CONSERVATION BOARD                                   

                               WELL LICENCES ISSUED  DAILY LIST                                     



DATE: 04 January 2010                                                                               


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
WELL NAME               LICENCE NUMBER         MINERAL RIGHTS       GROUND ELEVATION                
UNIQUE IDENTIFIER       SURFACE CO-ORDINATES   BOARD FIELD CENTRE   PROJECTED DEPTH                 
LAHEE CLASSIFICATION    FIELD                                       TERMINATING ZONE                
DRILLING OPERATION      WELL PURPOSE           WELL  TYPE           SUBSTANCE                       
LICENSEE                                                            SURFACE LOCATION                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        

SUNCOR ET AL MEDHAT 9-17-15-4        0416613   ALBERTA CROWN        753.3M                          
100/09-17-015-04W4/00  S  543.4M  W  167.6M    MEDICINE HAT         656.8M                        
DEV (NC)                             MEDICINE HAT                   FISH SCALE ZONE                 
VERTICAL                             NEW       PRODUCTION           GAS                             
SUNCOR ENERGY INC.                  

AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES
---------------------------

WELL NAME AND U.I.D.                LICENCE NO.  AMENDED TO READ
--------------------                -----------  ---------------

PARA ET AL HZ RE VALHALLA 4-34-75-11  0358541    TARGET SUBSTANCE(1)                                
100/04-34-075-11W6/02                            GAS FROM MONTNEY FM                                

SHPACIFIC OV MCKAY 2-17-91-14         0416002    TERMINATING ZONE:                                  
1AA/02-17-091-14W4/00                            WOODBEND GRP                                       

WELL LICENCES CANCELLED
-----------------------

WELL NAME AND U.I.D.                LICENCE NO.                                                     
--------------------                -----------                                                     

QRCI ET AL THREEHCK 14-19-36-26       0404101                                                       
100/14-19-036-26W4/00                                                                               

ARC ETAL 102 PEMBINA 15-34-48-8       0407157                                                       
100/15-34-048-08W5/00                                                                               


-------------------- END OF WELL LICENCES DAILY LIST  --------------------
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, is this your homework? Please share what have you done so far.

Comment: This is a bit of a hobby project. So not homework in the traditional sense of the word. I've figured out how to strip out the headers. I know how to rename my files to enable me to re-use  one cmd file to work on the series and I've figure out how to combine multiple csv's. At this point I've elected to process with cmd's to get one csv to enable me to import the result into any database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and with *pure batch*:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('^<file.txt find /n "AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES"') do set "LineFound=%%a"
echo "AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES" found in line #%LineFound%.
set /a LineFound-=1
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
<file.txt (
for /l %%a in (1,1,%LineFound%) do (
    set "Line="
    set/p "Line="
    echo(!Line!
))>file1.txt
endlocal
<file>file2.txt more +%LineFound%
type file?.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro works great.

Answer (score 2):

This is a robust method without loading extra tools, and uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

The input file is `file.txt`

```
type file.txt | findrepl    "." /e:"AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES"  /o:-1:-1 >file1.txt
type file.txt | findrepl /v "." /e:"AMENDMENTS OF WELL LICENCES"  /o:-1:-1 >file2.txt
```